# jquery/javascript if else statement not working, detecting empty textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code:

```
if ($('#txtEdit').val == '') {
    window.parent.$('#note' + appid + dbid).html('<img src="images/note_gray.png">');
} else if ($('#txtEdit').val != '') {
    window.parent.$('#note' + appid + dbid).html('<img src="images/note.png">');
};
```

I've also tried it with a simple "else" instead of the "else if".  I have also tried val(null) instead of val == ''.  In all instances, it will work one way, but not the other.  For example, as it is now (above) if I put something in the text box (txtEdit) it will set the div to note.png.  However, emptying the textbox will not change it to note_gray.png.

I am new to jquery/javascript.  Sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Neither of your comparisons is valid.  [`val`](http://api.jquery.com/val) is a function that returns a string.  It is not a property.

```
if ($('#txtEdit').val() == '') {
    window.parent.$('#note' + appid + dbid).html('<img src="images/note_gray.png">');
} else { // else if unnecessary
    window.parent.$('#note' + appid + dbid).html('<img src="images/note.png">');
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Call `val()`

```
if ($('#txtEdit').val() == '') {
```

with the parens, also, as a good practice, use `===` and `!==` to check for equality or not.

Comment: Carissimo Alberto, why is === better than == ?  (thanks ina advance!)

Comment: @roXon - it isn't "better", nor "good practice" in this case. `==` is the equals operator, it uses the abstract equality comparison algorithm to compare the expressions being evaluated. It's often called a *truthy* comparison. `===` is the strict equals operator and uses the **strict** equality comparison algorithm, which includes the type of the expressions being compared, e.g. `0==''` and `0==false` are both true, but `0===''` and `0===false` are both false. See ECMAScript section 11.9.

Comment: @RobG: in this case it's not a good practice, I was talking in general.